# How to disable to the review page for event registration in CiviEvent?

Tags: civievent

A lot of times people who register mistake the review page for the confirmation page and assume they have successfully registered for the event. This creates a headache for paid events. Is there a way to disable review page and register the participant directly without showing the review page.

Answer (score 1):

[Skip confirmation extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/skipeventconfirmpage) provides a settings on every event page settings to turn on/off confirmation/review page.